# Finding a formula for a sequence or proving it is impossible

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, pattern-recognition

I tried to search for a formula that produces the following sequence:
35
49
55
65
77
85
91
95
115

Etc, a larger sequence is in the following link:
https://pastebin.com/HDDHe7bz

Or proving that such formula is impossible.

I have asked more people and it is possible but the complexity of the formula grows it means it takes a lot of time to calculate large numbers.

The only requirement is that the formula should not grow exponentially in complexity for larger values.

A personal computer should be able to calculate lets say the millionth number of the sequence in less than 2 seconds, and the two millionth in less than 3 secs for example.

Comment: You can always find a polynomial $f$ with $f(1),\ldots ,f(n)$ giving your values.

Comment: check https://oeis.org/A038509 It looks like there is no formula to generate a sequence member

Comment: Can you please tell me how you manufacture this sequence?

Comment: a side project im playing with numbers doing all sorts of things it is too large to post it what i can say is that i have found some problems which will be fixed with the formula im looking for.

Comment: It has been suggested that your numbers are those congruent to $\pm 1 \bmod 6$ which are not prime (composite), starting at $35$.  Perhaps you should edit your Question to address this.  In any case you have said nothing about how you produced this sequence, and I am reluctant to explain further if you do not wish to provide a clarification of the source.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By Lagrange interpolation you can find a 8th degree polynomial such that 
$$P(1)=35; P(2)=49; P(3)= 55; P(4)= 65; P(5)= 77; P(6)= 85; P(7)= 91; P(8)= 95; P(9)= 115$$

You can even find infinitely many polynomials of higher degree satisfying these requirement: $$P(x)+h(x)(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)(X-5)(X-6)(X-7)(X-8)(X-9)$$
where $h$ is any polynomial. You can even replace $h$ by an arbitrary function.

Comment: Please help me what would be the way to get the millionth number of the sequence, i mean this may be a random sequence

Answer (score 1):

### The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences

#### Pseudoprimes

> So, we can say that 25, 35, 49, 55, 65, 77, 85, 91, … are pseudoprimes with respect to the property of being of the form $\{\displaystyle 6n-1\ \} \times \{\displaystyle 6n-1\ \}$ or $\{\displaystyle 6n+1\ \} \{\displaystyle 6n+1\ \}$

[Pseudoprimes](https://oeis.org/wiki/Pseudoprimes)

#### Other methods

[A038509 Composite numbers congruent to +-1 mod 6.](https://oeis.org/A038509)

[A067793 Nonprimes n such that phi(n) > 2n/3.](https://oeis.org/A067793)

[A287918 Union of nonprime 1 <= t <= m for m in A036913, with gcd(t,m) = 1.](https://oeis.org/A287918)